# npx create-react-app throwing Missing dependencies error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using `npx create-react-app client` `npm init react-app my-app` and also `create-react-app client` to build react.js directory for my MERN project.

But it keeps on throwing this Missing dependencies in package.json

```
npx create-react-app client

Creating a new React app in D:\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.8.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

The thing that I don't understand is that All the dependencies required is created by the command starting from values to package.json file as a user there is nothing I could do in this, but yet it throws missing dependencies error.

I have also post this problem on their github issues section. But apparently there is no reply.

Any help regarding this issue would be helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: btw - the way I would be resolving this is googling `info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.` and then checking the github issues results

Comment: latest node 10.14.1 @dwjohnston

Comment: Have you tried running `npm outdated` or `npm outdated -g`

Comment: I have done it but it's just showing express as outdated one. @Chimera.Zen

Comment: Try running `npm update express -g` with and without the -g when you&#39;re in the app folder